# How is an ASR's output compared to ground truth for validation?

Tags: nlp, similarity, speech-to-text

I am curious how it is done as I am interested in doing something similar. I have some manually transcribed data that contains tags for multiple speakers. I want to compare how well the out of the box ASRs (Google, AWS Transcribe) are able to diarise speakers (or in simple words identify and transcribe audio with multiple speakers). I want to compare it to the ground truth data I have and come up with a comparison metric.

I can use Levenshtein Distance or something like Ratcliff-Obershelp similarity as a metric. But I am trying to learn if there is a more standard way of doing this?

Comment: [This repository](https://github.com/syhw/wer_are_we) appears to track progress in ASR, it links many recent papers so I would assume that they use state of the art evaluation methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I was looking for is [Word Error Rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_error_rate). It is the most standard way of comparing ASR transcriptions wrt ground truth. It is less granular than what I had in mind, it is basically Levenshtein Distance on a word level rather than a character level.

[jiwer](https://pypi.org/project/jiwer/) in python has a few other metrics and is easy to use.